# Url rewrite doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have tried to rewrite the URL but if I run my application on the
 localhost they don't change

```
<system.web>
        <urlMappings enabled="true">
          <clear/>
          <!--Account-->
          <add url="~/Paswoord" mappedUrl="~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx"/>
          <!--Admin-->
          <add url="~/AddUsers" mappedUrl="~/Admin/AddUser.aspx"/>
          <add url="~/DeleteUsers" mappedUrl="~/Admin/DeleteUser.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
    <system.web>
```

Comment: Is your url Paswoord really spelled that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works
Default.aspx:

```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Password">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/AddUsers">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/DeleteUsers">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

webconfig:

```
 <system.web>
            <urlMappings enabled="true">
              <clear/>
              <!--Account-->
              <add url="~/Password" mappedUrl="~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx"/>
              <!--Admin-->
              <add url="~/AddUsers" mappedUrl="~/Admin/AddUser.aspx"/>
              <add url="~/DeleteUsers" mappedUrl="~/Admin/DeleteUser.aspx"/>
        </urlMappings>
    <system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this

http://www.urlrewriting.net/160/en/documentation.html

and download documentation given and try accordingly....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `url` is not pointing to an aspx page. Try

```
  <!--Account-->
  <add url="~/Paswoord.aspx" mappedUrl="~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx"/>
  <!--Admin-->
  <add url="~/AddUsers.aspx" mappedUrl="~/Admin/AddUser.aspx"/>
  <add url="~/DeleteUsers.aspx" mappedUrl="~/Admin/DeleteUser.aspx"/>
```